# How to get sibling element by its class name and then hide it using Javascript only?

Tags: javascript, html, element

I have this html structure:

```
  <div id="xyz"> </div>
  <div class="content"> </div>
```

i want to hide the element with class named **content** given the sibling element id which is **xyz** , in jQuery i can easily do it like this:

```
$("#xyz").siblings('.content').css({"dispaly": "none"});
```

how can i achieve the same thing using pure Javascript only ?

Comment: Does this help https://gomakethings.com/finding-the-next-and-previous-sibling-elements-that-match-a-selector-with-vanilla-js/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.querySelector("#xyz + .content").style.display = "none";
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5p7wfxr/)

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("xyz").nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("xyz").nextSibling;
while(true){   
   if(typeof(x) === "undefined"){
      break;
   }else if( x.className === "content"){
      x.style.display = 'none';
   }

   x = x.nextSibling;
}
```

Sorry, this code i still not testing yet.

Answer (score -1):

what about just

```
document.getElementsByClassName("content")
```

u can use it like

```
document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].style.display = "none"
```

Comment: While the following code might produce the same desired output. It is not the direct answer to the problem presented by the question (i.e. How to use the class name of an element to select it's sibling with a given class name?). The above solution only satisfies a specific html content and will fail on a different structure that may have the same requirements.