# Only the first button fires with AJAX and EJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, ejs

I have a EJS template which gets included on a page by running a for loop. Each template has a link which when clicked should toggle the display/hiding of a number of checkboxes. I am trying to use AJAX and have a javascript file which is linked to the template. In this javascript file I add an eventlistener to the link on that template. However only the link on the first template on the page fires.

The EJS template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/categorieslist.css">

<article class="post-item" id="<%= user.UserID %>" data-userId="<%= user.UserID %>">
  <p>
      <%= user.Email %>
      <input type="hidden" class="hiddenField" id="userid" name="userid" value="<%= user.UserID %>" required>
      <p><%= user.UserID %></p>
      <a class="btn catbtn" href="/admin-usercategories/<%= user.UserID %>/edit">Edit Call</a> 
      <div class="categorieslist">
         <% for (const cat of categories) { %>
          <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="<%= cat.CategoryID %>" value="<%= cat.CategoryID %>">
            <label for="<%=cat.CategoryID %>"><%= cat.CategoryName %></label>
          </p>
          <% } %>

        </div>
     </p>
</article>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/usercategories.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The javascript file:

```
const btn = document.querySelector(".catbtn");
const displayElement = document.querySelector(".categorieslist");

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    fetchUserCategories();
});

async function fetchUserCategories() {
    if (displayElement.style.display === "none") {
        displayElement.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        displayElement.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However only the link on the first template on the page fires.

Because a click handler is only being attached to one element.  This finds *an element*:

```
const btn = document.querySelector(".catbtn");
```

Even the variable name implies this.  And then the usage of the variable indicates that it's just one element:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fetchUserCategories();
});
```

If you want to find multiple elements, you want `querySelectorAll`:

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".catbtn");
```

Then loop over the results to attach the click handlers:

```
for (let btn of btns) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    fetchUserCategories();
  });
}
```

Of course, this will lead to the next problem... Every button does exactly the same thing.  It "fetches user categories" on the *first* `displayElement`.  You probably want the immediate sibling element of the one which was clicked.  For example, you might pass the `nextElementSibling` to the function:

```
for (let btn of btns) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    fetchUserCategories(this.nextElementSibling);
  });
}
```

And then in `fetchUserCategories` use that element reference:

```
function fetchUserCategories(displayElement) {
  // "displayElement" was passed to the function
}
```

If the markup could change then you might want to try other approaches to get the sibling element.  For example:

- [How to get sibling element by its class name and then hide it using Javascript only?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68204249/328193)
- [get nearby sibling in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14477791/328193)

Techniques often include starting from the current element (`this`), traversing up the DOM to a common parent element, then selecting the target element from that parent.

Comment: Thank you. This works now. I also moved the javascript file from the template to the main page.

Answer (score 0):

As there are **more templates that have same structure with button having class catbtn**. Then you can update this part of your code:-

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".catbtn");
const displayElement = document.querySelector(".categorieslist");

for(let btn of btns){
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
       fetchUserCategories();
    });
}
```

Comment: @kbdev No worries. if It solve your problem. Mark this answer correct for future visitors. Thanks